# How to pass deprecate_large_types parameter to SQLAlchemy engine creation

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

How to pass additional 'deprecate_large_types' parameter to engine_stmt? I tried every possible way and all the time tables wont get created because of bad syntax. As far as I know LargeBinary type wont work without this in sql server.

deprecate_large_types=True

```
    server = 'xxxx'
    username = 'xxx'
    password = 'xxx'
    database = 'MemDB'
    driver = 'ODBC+DRIVER+17+for+SQL+Server'
    engine_stmt = 'mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}/{}?driver={}'.format(username,
                                                                    password,
                                                                    server,
                                                                    database,
                                                                    driver)
    
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_stmt)




class Img (Base):

    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    img = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    name = Column(Text(512), nullable=False)
    mimetype = Column(Text(512), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: try `sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_stmt, deprecate_large_types=True)`?

Comment: didnt work, I tried <code>engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mssql+pyodbc://xxxx:xxx@xxxx:1433/MemDB?"
        "driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
        "&deprecate_large_types=True"
    )<code> and it didnt work too

Comment: Have you tried either `create_engine(url, connect_args={'deprecate_large_types: True})` or `create_engine(url, execution_options={'deprecate_large_types: True})`?